# Accuracy Difference in Deep Learning - epochs and final accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a deep learning model for my project. The code for the same is as given below:

```
model = Sequential()
# Add an input layer 
model.add(Dense(22, activation='relu', input_shape=(22,)))
# Add one hidden layer 
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
# Add an output layer 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])                   
model.fit(x_train, gender_train,epochs=90, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
gender_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print(confusion_matrix(gender_test,gender_pred.round()))
print(classification_report(gender_test,gender_pred.round()))
print(accuracy_score(gender_pred.round(),gender_test))
```

The accuracy for each epoch is coming in 90s. (eg. 0.97). But, When I predict the gender and print the accuracy with the help of accuracy_score, it's just coming in  80s. How are these accuracies related? I am new to machine learning, any help would be appreciated.[image: Console output]

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly mix up two things. There are two sets general, `train set`: user for training and you got above `90+` accuracy and another set you used for `test` and you got `79` - which by the way a clear indication of **model overfitting**.

All your `confusion matrix`, `classification report`, and lastly `accuracy` measurements are done using the `test` set.  In your code,

```
model = Sequential()

# Add an input layer 
model.add(Dense(22, activation='relu', input_shape=(22,)))
# Add one hidden layer 
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
# Add an output layer 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])                   
model.fit(x_train, gender_train,epochs=90, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

This is the training part, and it properly `.fit` the training pairs - `x_train -> gender_train`. Now, after some `fitting` or some `epoch` later when we test the model on **unseen** data which never **NEVER** used for training, that eventually reveals the model's true performance. In your case, this **unseen** data is `x_test`.

```
gender_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print(confusion_matrix(gender_test,gender_pred.round()))
print(classification_report(gender_test,gender_pred.round()))
print(accuracy_score(gender_pred.round(),gender_test))
```

If performance on `x_test` set or **Unseen** data is low or very low compare to the training data (i.e. `x_train`), it's simply called **overfitting** and that's not expected. In your case, your model is suffering from **overfitting**.

#### How to overcome

To avoid **overfitting**, people generally do as follows:

- make a validation set for choosing hyper-parameter in training time
- strong data augmentation

I would recommend these two article to read to get some more idea. Hope that helps.

- [Overfitting and Underfitting With Machine Learning Algorithms](https://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-and-underfitting-with-machine-learning-algorithms/)
- [Underfitting vs. Overfitting (vs. Best Fitting) in Machine Learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/underfitting-overfitting-best-fitting-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=This%20situation%20where%20any%20given,is%20called%20an%20overfitting%20model.&text=On%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20if,call%20that%20an%20underfitting%20model.)

Answer (score 0):

The training and test accuracy scores are used to identify over-fitting. A training accuracy that is far higher than test accuracy indicates over-fitting.

Accuracy can be misleading because of the nature of how it is calculated. In your case you are predicting the gender which has two possible values `0` and `1`. If the data is imbalanced, e.g. if a large portion of the test data was of one class then predicting that class would provide a high accuracy score but it would not necessarily be true when the classifier is applied to other data.

```
Accuracy = ((True Positive) + (True Negative)) / (Total Population)
```

The Confusion Matrix enables an accurate assessment of the model performance.

True Positives (**TP**) − The case when both actual class & predicted class of data point is 1.

True Negatives (**TN**) − The case when both actual class & predicted class of data point is 0.

False Positives (**FP**) − The case when actual class of data point is 0 & predicted class of data point is 1.

False Negatives (**FN**) − The case when actual class of data point is 1 & predicted class of data point is 0.

Looking at your console output:
TP = 93,
FP = 27,
FN = 24,
TN = 101

Accuracy score : (93 + 101) / (93 + 27 + 24 + 101) = 0.7918367347

Precision : (TP) / (TP + FP) : 93 / (93 + 27) = 0.775

Recall : (TP) / (TP + FN) : 93 / (93 + 24) = 0.7948

Support is the number of samples of the true label in each class of target values. (120 are class 0, 125 are class 1)

F1-score : 2 * (Precision * Recall) / (Precision + Recall)

F1 score is the weighted average of the precision and recall. Its best value would be 1 and the worst would be 0.

Being able to interpret these variables will help you to better understand your model.

If you are only beginning your Machine Learning adventure, I'd highly recommend [Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). He explains everything you need to understand quite simply without too much mathematics.